# How to connect serial port using netmiko?

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to connect to serial port(COM7), but not seem to work.
Maybe I did wrong description in device.
Can anybody help me out?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import netmiko

device = {
"device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
"port": "COM7",
"username": "admin",
"password": "",
"secret": "secret"
}

conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
conn.enable()
output = conn.send_config_set([
        'no service dhcp',
        'service dhcp',
        'ip dhcp option format circuit_id',
        'attr 3 type 0 length-hidden 6 value string 2412533'])
print(output)
conn.disconnect()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 173, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.port = int(port)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'COM7'
```

Comment: It seems like the port is expected to be a number only.

Answer (score 1):

Serial settings are specified in serial_settings in the device definition.

```
device = {
"device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
"username": "admin",
"password": "",
"secret": "secret",
"serial_settings": {"port": "COM7"}
}
```

I don't have a serial device to test with, but I get an error looking for a COM port.

```
ValueError: device COM7 not found.
```

instead of it expecting an integer.

Default values for serial_settings from the netmiko source are:

```
    self.serial_settings = {
        'port': 'COM1',
        'baudrate': 9600,
        'bytesize': serial.EIGHTBITS,
        'parity': serial.PARITY_NONE,
        'stopbits': serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    }
```

from https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/netmiko/base_connection.py

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for an idea to use serial_settings.
However, there are some other errors with serial_settings below;
FYI, I can access to COM7 with USB console but the errors came.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\GTAC\test_automation\test\robot_test\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 173, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 146, in __init__
    comm_port = check_serial_port(comm_port)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\utilities.py", line 173, in check_serial_port
    return cdc.split()[0]
AttributeError: 'ListPortInfo' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in [check_serial_port](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/master/netmiko/utilities.py)  function that trying to split ListPortInfo object. 
Quick solution is monkey patch like this:

```
import netmiko
import serial.tools.list_ports

def my_check_serial_port(name):
    """returns valid COM Port."""
    try:
        cdc = next(serial.tools.list_ports.grep(name))
        return cdc.__str__().split()[0]
    except StopIteration:
        msg = "device {} not found. ".format(name)
        msg += "available devices are: "
        ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
        for p in ports:
            msg += "{},".format(str(p))
        raise ValueError(msg)

netmiko.base_connection.check_serial_port = my_check_serial_port
```