# How do I connect to NetMiko through a serial connection?

Tags: python, netmiko

How do I connect through Serial Bus on NetMiko? I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759704/how-to-connect-serial-port-using-netmiko) asked 3 years ago. However, it no longer seems relevant.

I have the following code.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "device_type": "aruba_osswitch",
    "username": "manager",
    "password": "",
    "serial_settings": {"port": "COM4"}
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)

output = net_connect.send_command("show version")

print(output)
```

I'm getting the error: ValueError: Either ip or host must be set.
However, since it's serial, it requires no host or ip as far as I'm aware. Could anyone advise?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, serial connections to aruba switches is not implemented in Netmiko. The only one I can see is for cisco devices. Whenever you want to connect to a device with a serial cable just append `_serial` to the device type. For cisco devices it would be something like `cisco_ios_serial`. If you want to do it yourself, try doing it using [`pyserial`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, unfortunately, serial connections to Aruba switches is not implemented in `Netmiko`. The only one I can see is for Cisco devices. Whenever you want to connect to a device with a serial cable just append `_serial` to the device type (If it's implemented in Netmiko). For Cisco devices it would be something like `{"device_type": "cisco_ios_serial"}`. If you want to do it yourself, try doing it using [`pySerial`](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) library.

> `Netmiko` already uses `pySerial` for serial connections.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TannerRayMartin/f0b91c5e492b1f15698656486403ef02) using `pySerial` APIs which is device agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I used this Code snip from: - https://semfionetworks.com/blog/establish-a-console-connection-within-a-python-script-with-pyserial/
An Ran this by modifying slightly on OpenSUSE OS

```
$import serial
$from time import sleep


$def send_to_console(ser: serial.Serial, command: str, wait_time: float = 0.5):
     $command_to_send = command + "\r"
     $ser.write(command_to_send.encode('utf-8'))
     $sleep(wait_time)
     $print(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()). decode('utf-8'), end="") 

$with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS8", timeout=1) as ser:
     $print(f"Connecting to {ser.name}...")
     $send_to_console(ser, "")
     $send_to_console(ser, "enable")
     $send_to_console(ser, "show ip interface brief", wait_time=2)
     $print(f"Connection to {ser.name} closed.")
```